# Node.js error Module not found error in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried running my Node.js program in VSCode, I tried various ways on StackOverflow but none of them are working. I have already tried the Json file method but it didn't work.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\study material TYBTECH\HTML CSS\HTML CSS\JavaScript\.Nodejs.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)      
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: A require() operation in your code mentions a nonexistent Javascript file. Please [edit] your question to show us some of your code.

Comment: try avoiding spaces in your project file path

Answer (score 0):

Move your file to parents folder than try to run it file. node_module and file which you what to run should be in same folder.